# JxBrowser get post body in custom ProtocolHandler

Tags: javascript, java, http-post, jxbrowser

In one of my projects I use the JxBrowser in a Netbeans application where my ReactApp is running. 
I want to send a post request from the ReactApp and intercept it in my custom Protocol Handler in the JxBrowser. 
The request is done via 'superagent':

```
request
    .post('http://my-url')
    .send({test: 'it'})
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .end(callback)
```

I receive the request in my ProtocolHandler but I do not know how to get the post body out of the request.

```
urlRequest.getUploadData() //<-- returns null
```

What is the correct way to get the posts body here?

Answer (score 0):

You're making a cross-origin request. A preflight "OPTIONS" request is sent in this case and you need to handle it properly in your ProtocolHandler. In this particular case you should set the certain headers telling the browser that the requested features are allowed:

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
    URLResponse urlResponse = new URLResponse();
    String origin = request.getRequestHeaders().getHeader("Origin");
    HttpHeadersEx headers = urlResponse.getHeaders();
    headers.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    headers.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    headers.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    urlResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
    return urlResponse;
}
```

Also, in order to allow JxBrowser to detect the POST data type properly, you should set the "Content-Type" request header with the corresponding value. In this case it should be the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

```
request
    .post('http://my-url')
    .send({test: 'it'})
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    .end(callback)
```

Then you'll receive a POST request with your data. I recommend that you take a look at the following article that contains the details related to CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

If you're making a request to the same origin, you can avoid handling cross-origin requests just by setting the proper "Content-Type" header.